# Application Insights: Console Application HttpClient correlation not working

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have a Console Application which I plan to use Application Insights to start telemetry. This Console App calls a Web API within it.

Operation correlation works, but the Parent hierarchy does not. Essentially, the **Parent** of the Web API call is not the initial call from Console Application.

Below is my code:

**Console App**

```
static async Task SendHttpOnly()
    {
        //Create TelemetryClient
        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        configuration.InstrumentationKey = "<id>";
        var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);

        RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry { Name = "ConsoleTest" };

        var operation = telemetryClient.StartOperation(requestTelemetry);

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:37970/");
                var responseTask = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<MessageDto>("MessageReceiver", new MessageDto() { Body = "Test" });
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            operation.Telemetry.Success = false;
            telemetryClient.TrackException(e);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
            telemetryClient.Flush();
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
        }

    }
```

**Web API**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody] MessageDto dto)
    {
        _telemetryClient.TrackTrace($"Service Bus Message Processed: Message: {dto.Body}");
        return $"Processed { dto.Body }";
    }
```

Weird thing is, if I do a Web API to Web API call, it logs it properly. Even with the same code; the 2nd Web API call parent is the 1st Web API call.

Comment: Can you check what's being sent over the wire in TraceParent header (and whether it exists or whether state it passed through different headers)?

Comment: I realized I was using the wrong NuGet package. I was using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore while I should be using the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService for console applications. Details are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service

Comment: I'd expect for regular SDK still to work here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou [Water](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946656/water). Glad that you resolved your issue and posting the same as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members.

Application HttpClient correlation not working because of using wrong Nuget package instead of using below package

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore
```

We need to use the below package

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService
```

Below is the sample code for using SDK in application insights.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.13.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

For more information check the [Application Insight worker service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#using-application-insights-sdk-for-worker-services).